# Outlook 2013 on laptop and PC display image signature in different sizes. Why?

Tags: image, email, outlook, signature

[image: Image on the left is on laptop, right is on PC]

I did it on Thunderbird then send it to my laptop. It looks fine on laptop. I save it as signature on laptop, then I send it to my PC. I save the signature to my PC. Then I send it back to laptop. The image size will resize to smaller one like on the left picture.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
    <tbody>
      <tr width="600" height="96">
       <td width="600" height="96" style="text-align:right">
        <img src="a"
            alt="">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            
       <td width="600" height="20" style="text-align:right">
       <a style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none!important; font-size:11px; color:#006c86!important;" href="#"><span style="color: #006c86; text-decoration: none"><font color="#006c86">this.com</font></span></a>  <font color="#006c86">|</font>  
       <a style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none!important;  font-size:11px; color:#006c86!important;" href="#"><span style="color: #006c86; text-decoration: none"><font color="#006c86">that.com</font></span></a>  <font color="#006c86">|</font>  
       <a style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none!important;  font-size:11px; color:#006c86!important;" href="#"><span style="color: #006c86; text-decoration: none"><font color="#006c86">all.com</font></span></a>&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is how the code looks like when I first put it in thunderbird. The image src i used data:image/jpeg;base64

Why does this happen? How to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of emails. All supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties are described in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Did you have a chance to check out the zoom level? When you hold the Ctrl button pressed try to scroll... Is the zoom level set to 100% all the time?

Did you have a chance to check out the HTML markup before and after? Is there any changes?

Comment: I just realised that the laptop has the text display set to 125%. Seems like I need to send the edm from my pc set to 125% too.